# Regex in swift. A template for a specific numeric format

Tags: regex, string, parsing, swift

I am new in swift, I have been working with it only few weeks and now I am trying to parse something like a price list from incoming string. It has the next format:
2.99 X 3.00 = 10 A
Some text here
1.22 X 1.5    10 A

And the hardest part is that sometime A or some digit is missing but X should be in the place.
I would like to find out how it is possible to use regex in swift (or something like that if it does not exist) to write a template for parsing the next value
d.dd X d.d   SomeValueIfExists

I would very appreciate any useful information, topics to read or any other resources to get more knowledge about swift.

PS. I have access to the dev. forums but I've never used them before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an example recentl, and maybe a little harder than necessary, to demonstrate RegEx use in Swift:

```
let str1: NSString = "I run 12 miles"
let str2 = "I run 12 miles"

let match = str1.rangeOfString("\\d+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
let finalStr = str1.substringWithRange(match).toInt()
let n: Double = 2.2*Double(finalStr!)

let newStr = str2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\d+", withString: "\(n)", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)

println(newStr) //I run 26.4 miles
```

Two of these have "RegularExpressionSearch".  If you put this in a playground you can see what each line does.  Note the double \ escapes.  One for the normal RegEx use and anther because \ is a special character in Swift.

Also a good article:

http://benscheirman.com/2014/06/regex-in-swift/

Comment: thank you. Does regex in swift have any difference than any others?
e.g. regex in .net
And maybe you can advice me some tool to test my regexp.

Comment: I think you just test in a playground.  I have only used RegEx in swift for a couple of weeks so not sure the differences from other environments.